# SSRS - Parameter based on reference table

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have multiple datasets with the WHERE clause = @customernumber.

I have a customer number data set that contains a field with a unique id and a field that contains multiple ids.

I.e.

```
Customer Number |   Old Customer Numbers
        123                 123
        123                 34324
        123                 4363
        123                 124214
        345                 345
        345                 436346
        345                 234532
        678                 678
```

I want to be able to search in the parameter box for the old customer number but use the customer number in querying my datasets.

My datasets only contain the customer number, not the old customer numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the parameter you can select the value and the label of the dropdown list.

In the `Available Values` tab select `Get values from a query`, for dataset just choose the dataset that query the table with new and old codes. In `Value field` select the new code and in the `Label field` select the old code.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

1. Create a parameter called `OldCode`. Set the data type to text or integer based on old customer code number. Don't use default or available values for this parameter.
2. Create a dataset that use the `@OldCode` parameter to return the customer number. Use something like this:

   ```
   select 
    Customer_Number
   from CustomerTable
   where Old_Customer_Number = @OldCode
   ```
3. Create a parameter called `CustomerNumber`. Set `Hidden` property and select the data type based on the `Customer_Number` column. In `Default Values` tab select the dataset created previously and the `Customer_Number` column as Value field.

After that you can use `@CustomerNumber` in all your datasets. When user input a old code the `@CustomerNumber` will be populated with the related `Customer_Number` value.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: When I tried this I got the following error:

 The report parameter ‘Customer_Number’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “Customer_Number”. Forward dependencies are not valid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @cpaprocki, Try deleting the parameter and create a new one. It seems you were playing around with that parameter and some settings in Default Values tab are causing errors.

Comment: I deleted the parameter and created a new one with the criteria that you suggested - I get the same error message.

Comment: @cpaprocki Does the dataset that feeds the Customer_Number parameter depend on another parameter?

Comment: For the code for my customer number dataset, I did have the same where clause as my measures data sets (WHERE Customer_Number= @customernumber.

I removed that and now the report will run, but the parameter is a drop down menu. The Customer_Number table has 550,000 rows, so it is very slow to run. 

Is there a way to keep the box as a field that can have freeform data entry?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @cpaprocki If you want the user type the old customer code but parameter be set with the new customer code you have to create two parameter one for the user input and another to hold the new code which you will pass to your datasets to filter the rows returned. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I am not sure how to set this up, is there an example you could link?